# Reduce link (URL) size

Tags: php, javascript, url, hyperlink, reduce

Is it possible to reduce the size of a link (in text form) by PHP or JS?

E.g. I might have links like these:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html                     <- Redirects to the root
http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=true   <- Redirects to page.html
http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=false  <- Redirects to page.html?start=false
```

The purpose is to find out, if the link can be shortened and still point to the same location. In these examples the first two links can be reduces, because the first points to the root, and the second has parameters that can be omitted.
The third link is then the case, where the parameters can't be omitted, meaning that it can't be reduced further than to remove the `http://`.

So the above links would be reduced like this:

```
Before: http://www.example.com/index.html
After:  www.example.com

Before: http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=true
After:  www.example.com/folder1/page.html

Before: http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=false
After:  www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=false
```

Is this possible by PHP or JS?

**Note:**

`www.example.com` is not a domain I own or have access to besides through the URL. The links are potentially unknown, and I'm looking for something like an automatic link shortener that can work by getting the URL and nothing else.

Actually I was thinking of something like a linkchecker that could check if the link works before and after the automatic trim, and if it doesn't then the check will be done again at a less trimmed version of the link. But that seemed like overkill...

Comment: is www.example.com YOUR website (i.e. it is controlled by you) or is www.example.com ANY website?

Comment: If you have server access, I suggest .htaccess `RedirectRule`'s

Comment: No, they are not my domains. Se the added note above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do this automatically, and you don't know how the parameters change the behaviour, you will have to do this by trial and error: Try to remove parts from an URL, and see if the server responds with a different page.

In the simplest case this could work somehow like this:

```
<?php
    $originalUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135342/reduce-link-url-size";

    $originalContent = file_get_contents($originalUrl);

    $trimmedUrl = $originalUrl;

    while($trimmedUrl) {
        $trialUrl = dirname($trimmedUrl);
        $trialContent = file_get_contents($trialUrl);
        if ($trialContent == $originalContent) {
            $trimmedUrl = $trialUrl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo "Shortest equivalent URL: " . $trimmedUrl;
    // output: Shortest equivalent URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135342
?>
```

For your usage scenario, your code would be a bit more complicated, as you would have to test for each parameter in turn to see if it is necessary. For a starting point, see the [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) functions.

A word of caution: this code is very slow, as it will perform lots of queries to every URL you want to shorten. Also, it will likely fail to shorten many URLs because the server might include stuff like timestamps in the response. This makes the problem very hard, and that's the reason why companies like google have many engineers that think about stuff like this :).

Comment: Now you're just telling him to spam a external server with requests, bad idea, bad practice, not to mention inconsiderate to both the host of the external address, as the "local" host.

Comment: I guess the nice thing to do would be to check `robots.txt` first. But I tried to answer the question rather than say "it can't be done". Any server that would have trouble with this kind of load should better not be connected to the internet. Any webserver gets thousands of such "spam" requests, either by error, from google, or from people scanning for vulnerabilities...

Comment: That'd be a start, yea. However, like you said, timestamps might be included, there might be a visit counter / clock on the page, the page might contain dynamic / random content.
In theory, this might work, but practically? No way.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, that's possible:

JS:

```js
var url = 'http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=true';
url = url.replace('http://','').replace('?start=true','').replace('/index.html','');
```

php:

```php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/folder1/page.html?start=true';
$url = str_replace(array('http://', '?start=true', '/index.html'), "", $url);
```

(Each item in the `array()` will be replaced with `""`)

Comment: Okay, well I need something automatic. I might not know the URL.

Comment: So, you need to change it for the "current page"?

Comment: What do you mean by current page? See my note to the question; I have many links that I want to print on a website. The links must first be shortened as much as possible, since they can be full of extra unneeded characters.

Comment: Do you have an array of these links or something like that? You can just loop through the links and apply my code to each of them. There is however no way to accurately strip url parameters, unless you're manually specifying them, like I did.

Comment: I have them in a DB. I was hoping to find something automatic and not manual, since the links are not alike and have different extra parameters and stuff.

Comment: Then what's stopping you from looping through the urls and using `str_replace` on them?
There is no accurate way to remove only __some__ url parameters. either remove them all, remove none, or handcode exceptions. (You can't reliably check if the removed parameter changes the link's result)

Comment: Would the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: I voted the post down because it doesn't answer the question. The OP was obviously looking for an automatic way to remove superfluous arguments from URLS, rather than advise how to perform basic string manipulation.

Comment: Sometimes, what an OP wants is not reasonably possible, but there might be solutions that come close to the functionality that was requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS for you.

```
function trimURL(url, trimToRoot, trimParam){
    var myRegexp = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*)/g;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(url);
    url = match[2];
    //alert(url);  // www.google.com
    if(trimParam===true){
        url = url.split('?')[0];
    }
    if(trimToRoot === true){
        url = url.split('/')[0];
    }
    return url
}

alert(trimURL('https://www.google.com/one/two.php?f=1'));
alert(trimURL('https://www.google.com/one/two.php?f=1', true));
alert(trimURL('https://www.google.com/one/two.php?f=1', false, true));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5aRpQ/